# MySQL: using "NOT IN" clause correctly

Tags: mysql, sql, database

[image]

The problem is :Find the employee last names for employees who do not work on any projects.

My solution is:

```
SELECT E.Lname 
FROM EMPLOYEE E
WHERE E.Ssn NOT IN (SELECT * 
                    FROM EMPLOYEE E,WORKS_ON W
                    WHERE E.Ssn = W.Essn);
```

This should subtract the ssns from employee from the essns from works_on, However I keep getting the error "Operand should contain 1 column". What does this mean and how can I correct this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE.Lname FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPLOYEE.SSN NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT WORKS_ON.Essn FROM WORKS_ON);
```

Comment: You did not connect table employee to table dependent anywhere. Is that not necessary?

Comment: Because your problem is only find the employee last names for employees who do not work on any projects.

Answer (score 1):

The result of a NOT IN subquery must be one value. Your subquery returns all the columns in the `EMPLOYEE` and `WORKS_ON` tables. You can use NOT EXISTS instead:

```
SELECT E.Lname 
FROM EMPLOYEE E
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM WORKS_ON W
                  WHERE E.Ssn = W.Essn);
```

The `1` could be any scalar, or it could even be NULL.

Comment: What is the difference between NOT IN and NOT EXISTS and what does the 1 mean here?

Comment: Check out this question and answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists

Comment: @DanteGreyson *NOT EXISTS* perform better than *IN*.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT E.Lname 
FROM EMPLOYEE E
WHERE E.Ssn NOT IN (SELECT E.Ssn 
                    FROM EMPLOYEE E,WORKS_ON W
                    WHERE E.Ssn = W.Essn);
```

not in , means not include the another value sets.
So, in the next query, it should select the value set.

```
SELECT E.Ssn 
FROM EMPLOYEE E,WORKS_ON W
WHERE E.Ssn = W.Essn
```

this part will be return all of the employee's SSN who has worked.

hope it explain your questions

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT E.Lname 
FROM EMPLOYEE E
WHERE E.Ssn NOT IN (SELECT distinct Essn 
                    FROM WORKS_ON);
```